# Classification of Quantum Phenomena?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to figure out a kind of taxonomy of quantum phenomena. So far the categories I've come up with are (in historical order, with example phenomena):

1. discrete quantities where continuous ones are expected (black-body spectrum, atomic spectra, Stern-Gerlach [spin spectra]),
2. interference phenomena where trajectories are expected (double slit experiment), and
3. long distance entanglement correlations (Bell's inequality phenomena).

Am I missing anything major from this list? Did I incorrectly group something that should be in its own class? Can any of these classes be merged?

As requested, how I would define classical phenomena: anything that behaves according to classical mechanics - objects that have (approximately enough) definite position and momentum that obey Newton's laws (even the relativistic versions), and waves that have infinitely variable amplitude, even when boundary conditions limit the frequency spectrum.

Basically, I'm trying to get a clear picture of what the boundary between classical and quantum phenomena looks like.

Comment: What would you consider to be a phenomenon that is *not* quantum? I think you need to define this before your question can be answered.

Comment: Maybe indistinguishability of particles and consequences for the qm description of fermions and bosons (wave function symmetries, Pauli principle, Fermi- and Bose-Einsetin statistics) might be something major for your list.